# WordPress Pagination Problems - disappearing next_posts_link

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination

I was hoping someone could help me address an issue I've been having trying to paginate a custom template in WordPress. I've scoured through Stackoverflow and other website forums looking for answers related to this, but no one seems to have problems exactly like the one I'm having.

I am currently making changes to a WordPress site built by a predecessor and on one of the pages shows our company portfolio. This showed all the posts we have published (as work) until I recently changed it to 12 per page. However, I can't seem to get the pagination to work or the posts_links top even appear on the page.

The page in question is http://thefabl.com/our-work and the code I currently have on the page (just from the top of the loop to the footer), is as stands below:

```
<?php
            $cases = 1;
            $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
            $args = array(
                'post_type' => 'work',
                'posts_per_page' => 12,
                'post_status' => 'publish',
                'paged' => $paged,
                'orderby' => 'date',
                );

            if ( isset( $_GET[ 'project' ] ) ) {
                $args[ 'project' ] = $_GET[ 'project' ];
            }
            $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
            if ( $loop->have_posts() ) : while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
        ?>
                <li <?php if ( ( $cases % 3 ) == 0 ) { echo ' class="end"'; } ?>>
                    <div class="overlay absolute-full">
                        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="absolute-full"></a>
                    </div>
                    <figure>
                        <?php 
                            if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {

                                the_post_thumbnail( 'work_list' );

                            } else {

                                echo '<img src="http://placehold.it/298x175" alt="Placeholder"/>';

                            }
                        ?>
                    </figure>
                    <div class="post-meta">
                        <p class="title">
                            <?php the_title(); ?>
                        </p>
                        <span class="work-type">
                            <?php the_field( 'work_type' ); ?>
                        </span>
                    </div>

                </li>

        <?php
            $cases++;
            endwhile; ?>

            <div class="main" id="post-pagination">
                <?php if( has_previous_posts() ){ ?><div class="prev"><?php echo previous_posts_link( 'Previous Page' ); ?></div><?php } ?>
                <?php if( has_next_posts() ){ ?><div class="next"><?php echo next_posts_link( 'Next Page' ); ?></div><?php } ?>
            </div>

        <?php   endif; ?>

    </ul>

</div>

<a class="back-to-top bottom center"></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps `echo` causing the problem. Please use following lines.

```
<div class="next"><?php next_posts_link('&laquo; Older Entries') ?></div>
<div class="prev"><?php previous_posts_link('Newer Entries &raquo;') ?></div>
```

Hope it will work for you.

and if you are showing posts on homepage, you may need to replace

```
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
```

with

```
<?php

if ( get_query_var('paged') ) 
    { 
        $paged = get_query_var('paged'); 
    } 
else if ( get_query_var('page') ) 
    {
        $paged = get_query_var('page'); 
    }
    else 
    {
        $paged = 1; 
    }
```

Comment: Hi Sukhdeep Kaur, sorry for being so slow to reply.
Thank you for the suggestions, but this hasn't helped. The page I am trying to paginate isn't the homepage, it's a custom template

Comment: I tried to use the post_links code from the blog page to use with the loop on this page. 

Maybe it's clashing with the taxonomy filters...?